# The first part before dot operator of the PostgreSQL service host name is not validated by the IBM PostgreSQL cloud service

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We have IBM Cloud PostgreSQL instance. We are connecting to it using node-postgres client or odbc client with Data Direct Driver. As per our understanding the PostgreSQL service instance should throw error when provide incorrect host while connecting. However, the instance is not throwing any error when providing incorrect host (incorrect value for the first part of the host string before dot operator).

Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create IBM Cloud PostgreSQL instance. Below is the format of host string
   `<<1st part of host>>.<<2nd part of host>>.databases.appdomain.cloud`
2. Connect to instance using node client using node-postgres client or odbc client with Data Direct Driver with incorrect value for the first portion(`<<1st part of host>>`) of the host.
3. It will connect successfully without any issue. If we provide incorrect value(`<<2nd part of host>>.databases.appdomain.cloud`) for remaining portion it throws error.

Used below code snippet for validating this scenario:

```js
const pg = require('pg')
const connectionString = 'postgres://user:password@<<1st part of host>>.<<2nd part of host>>.databases.appdomain.cloud:31974/ibmclouddb?sslmode=verify-full'
const caCert = 'Self Signed CA Certificate'
const client = new pg.Client(
  {
    connectionString: connectionString,
    ssl: {
      ca: caCert,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
)
client.connect()
client.query('select * from test_pg.char_test4').then(res => {
  console.log('res.rows :::::: ', res)
}).finally(() => client.end())
```

Comment: This only happens in hostnames including a . ?

Comment: Yes @drnugent, There are different parts in hostname and first part is not validating by the PostgreSQL service while connecting with incorrect value which is major issue.